# Resurrecting Postgres Snapshot from AWS and the postgres user can't see public schema?

Tags: postgresql, amazon-web-services, privileges

I just had to resurrect a snapshot of a postgres AWS database that got corrupted. We had two users: `postgres` and `limited`.
When I get into the new snapshot db as the postgres user, I find that I can't select anything in the `public` schema.

I see that the owner of the `public` schema is `postgres` however only the `limited` user can access anything. I tried granting every privilege I could find, even ALL, however the `postgres` user still can't see `public`. I even granted the `limited` role to `postgres` however it still doesn't work.

What am I missing here?

Comment: Best ask Amazon.